# How to perform Git actions on a part of a file inside CLion?

Tags: c++, git, visual-studio-code, clion

Currently, I'm migrating my C++ workflow from [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) to the [CLion IDE](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/). One thing that I missing from the Visual Studio Code is the possibility to `stage/unstag` and `revert` only some selected lines from a file that I'm currently editing. Is this possible in **CLion** and how if it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to open the commit tool, default keybinding is `Alt + 0` which allows you to select the chunks you want to commit.

The documentation for this is here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/commit-and-push-changes.html#partial_commit